# Submenu placement HTML

Tags: html, css

I made my submenu appear when I hover over one option in menu. However when I do it it extends menu height ([PIC1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjLTp.png)). I tried setting menu height on 56px and then it doesn't extend but it ruins my whole layout ([PIC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY2wz.png)). I also tried putting position:absolute in empty div between menu_option and submenu but then submenu changes sizes and loses attributes (PIC3).

```css
#menu {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #73818c;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu_option {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: dotted 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.submenu {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px black;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.submenu:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.menu_option:hover div {
  display: block;
}
.menu_option:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu_option">Strona główna</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Galeria</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Reżyserzy
    <div>
      <div class="submenu" style="margin-top:10px">Quentin Tarantino</div>
      <div class="submenu">Bracia Coen</div>
      <div class="submenu">Wes Anderson</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_option">Ulubione filmy</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Seriale</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Kontakt</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: PIC3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzjtO.png

Comment: Whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/0xx0teku/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `position: absolute` on the div that holds the `submenu`s (and `position: relative` on the menu options) will keep the height of that div (and its contents) from affecting the height of its parent elements.

```css
#menu {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #73818c;
  padding: 10px;
}

 #menu, #menu * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.menu_option {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: dotted 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

/* I've added this class to the div around the .submenus */
.submenu_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightgray;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  }

.submenu {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px black;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.submenu:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.menu_option:hover div {
  display: block;
}
.menu_option:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu_option">Strona główna</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Galeria</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Reżyserzy
    <div class="submenu_wrapper"> <!-- new class -->
      <div class="submenu" style="margin-top:10px">Quentin Tarantino</div>
      <div class="submenu">Bracia Coen</div>
      <div class="submenu">Wes Anderson</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_option">Ulubione filmy</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Seriale</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Kontakt</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add to the end of your CSS

```
    menu_option:hover > div{
     position:absolute;
    top:10px;

    }
.menu_option
{
  position:relative;
  }
```

Here is an [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/c0uumy80/)

Answer (score 0):

add an id named `main_bx` to the div that holds all divs with class `.submenu` and

```
.main_bx{
display:none;
}
.menu_option:hover  .main_bx {
  display: block;
 position:absolute;

}

#menu {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #73818c;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

**see snippet below (The window is small so you are going to find some wrapping in this snippet)**

```css
#menu {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #73818c;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu_option {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: dotted 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.submenu,.main_bx {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px black;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 
  font-size: 13px;
}
.submenu:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.main_bx{
display:none;
}
.menu_option:hover  .main_bx {
  display: block;
 position:absolute;
  
}
.menu_option:hover{
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
#menu {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #73818c;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu_option">Strona główna</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Galeria</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Reżyserzy
    <div class="main_bx">
      <div class="submenu" style="margin-top:10px">Quentin Tarantino</div>
      <div class="submenu">Bracia Coen</div>
      <div class="submenu">Wes Anderson</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_option">Ulubione filmy</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Seriale</div>
  <div class="menu_option">Kontakt</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```